# Rails 3: How to display data of multiple intra-dependent models in a table in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, associations

I have a betting application, where users can bet on sports matches (e.g. basketball). I have something like this:

```
Group has_many   :users
Group belongs_to :league
League has_many  :matches
Match has_many   :bets
User has many    :bets

Bet belongs_to :group
Bet belongs_to :match
Bet belongs_to :user
```

As you can see, users bet in groups. A group bets on one league (e.g. soccer season 2011/2012) and a league consists of many matches, that can be betted on.

I want to render the view for an action in the Group Controller (so Group is the base model). It should display a table with the matches on the horizontal table header and the users on the vertical table header. A table cell should show the bet of a user for the given match, like so:

```
       | Team 1 vs Team 2 | Team 3 vs Team 4
=======+==================+=================
User 1 |       1 : 2      |       0 : 0
-------+------------------+-----------------
User 2 |       2 : 0      |       1 : 0
```

**Now the question is: how to best setup access to my data?**

I could set up the @group attribute in the controller and then access data in the view like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <% for match in @group.league.matches %>
        <th><%= "#{match.team1.name} vs. #{match.team2.name}" %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% for user in @group.users %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= user.name %></th>
        <% for match in @group.league.matches %>
          <td><%= ?????? %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My problem is denoted with "??????": How to access the correct bet?**

```
match.bets.find_by_group_id_and_user_id( ... ) # this will generate a new SELECT on DB
match.bets.to_a.find{|bet| bet.user_id == user.id && bet.group_id == @group.id}.home_score # seems cluttered and should not belong in the view
```

Your input on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if I'm understanding correctly:

```
<% for user in @group.users %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= user.name %></th>
    <% for match in @group.league.matches %>
      <% bet = Bet.find_by_user_id_and_match_id(user.id, match.id) %>
      <td><%= bet.whatever.. %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In response to your comment, you could put this stuff in a hash table in the controller like so:

```
@users = @group.users
@user_bets = @users.inject({}) do |hsh, user|
  hsh[user] = {}
  @group.league.matches.each do |match|
    hsh[user][match] = .. # look up the Bet and assign it here
  end
  hsh
end
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for the response. Yes, that works (if I add another dynamic condition for the group), but then access to the model is not encapsulated in the controller. Is there another solution that corresponds with the MVC pattern or is this acceptable for the situation at hand?

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's far from optimal. The only other way I see of doing it is building a hash that looks something like: { :user => {:match => :bet}, {:match => :bet}...}

Comment: Thanks for the update, Jimmy. Although I was hoping rails would offer a simpler solution, I think the inject (or each_with_object instead) will work for me. +1 and accepted :) Thanks again.